# I'd like help optimizing code which deletes matching models in a big queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a snippet of django code which is intended to iterate a queryset of models and to delete any matching ones. The queryset has gotten large, and these actions are actually set to a periodic task, so the speed is becoming a problem.

Here is the code, if anyone is willing to try to help optimize it!

```
# For the below code, "articles" are just django models

all_articles = [a reallly large list of articles]
newest_articles = [some large list of new articles]
unique_articles = []
for new_article in newest_articles:
    failed = False
    for old_article in all_articles:
        # is_similar is just a method which checks if two strings are
        # identical to a certain degree
        if is_similar(new_article.blurb, old_article.blurb, 0.9) 
            and is_similar(new_article.title, old_article.title, 0.92):
            failed = True
            break
    if not failed:
        unique_articles.append(new_article)
return unique_articles
```

Thanks you guys!

Comment: Can you define `is_similar()` in database operations?

Comment: None as far as I know, it just compares two input strings for equality.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any efficient way of implementing "fuzzy DISTINCT" at the SQL level, so I would recommend taking the pre-computation route. 
Trying to guess your business logic from a small code snippet, so this might be off base, but sounds like you just need to know for every new article if it has older dupes (as defined by is_similar function). In that case a viable approach might be adding an `is_duplicate` field to the Article model and recomputing it in a background job whenever an article is saved. E.g. (using [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/%20Celery)):

```
@task
def recompute_similarity(article_id):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
    article.is_duplicate = False
    for other in Article.objects.exclude(id=article_id):
        if is_similar(article.title, other.title) or is_similar(article.blurb, other.blurb):
            article.is_duplicate = True
            break
     article.save()

def on_article_save(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if not raw:
        recompute_similarity.delay(instance.id)

signals.post_save.connect(on_article_save, sender=Article)
```

Then your original routine will be reduced to just

```
Article.objects.filter(is_duplicate=False, ...recency condition)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill try this and the implementations others post

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this might be to maintain a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) index of the content with [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/), then search Solr for matches on each article, and then feed the top several matches for each into the is_similar function. Not having to search the entire dataset to find similar articles would make a fairly large difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i'll try to implement this.